# Medical term for fear of not being outdoors enough

Tags: single-word-requests

Sometime ago i came across an online article that describes a condition (from my experience very real) when someone starts physically suffering from not spending enough time outdoors and too much time in the city.  The article gave such condition a very particular name and, for the love of God, i cannot recall what that name was.  Must be one of the `***-phobia` or `$$$-mania` with a greek stem. Does anyone know what I am referring to?

Alternatively, the term i am looking for could possibly stand for "acute feeling of discomfort from being a part of civilized world".

Comment: You seem to be describing several different (if somewhat related) experiences. The fear of not being outdoors enough isn't really the same as the feeling of discomfort from being a part of civilized world.

Comment: Google “nature-deficit disorder.”

Comment: Sounds a little like the well-known medical term *cabin fever*, which M-W defines as "extreme irritability and restlessness from living in isolation or a confined indoor area for a prolonged time." It fits your question title and the first part of the body of your question. :-)

Comment: Quite the opposite of what you describe is *[agoraphobia](https://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/agoraphobia)*, the fear of being outdoors. Does this help jog your memory?

Comment: I agree that "suffering from being trapped in a city" and "feeling of discomfort from being a part of the civilized world" are not exactly the same.  I was just trying to broaden the scope in hope that the word i am looking for falls somewhere within.  Could have phrased it better, indeed.

Comment: Claustrophobia, Autophobia, eremophobia?

Answer (score 2):

If it's an antiquated medical term, it may be related to what the opening line of 'Moby Dick' describes, having to do with 'spleen.'

"Call me Ishmael. Some years ago—never mind how long precisely—having little or no money in my purse, and nothing particular to interest me on shore, I thought I would sail about a little and see the watery part of the world. It is a way I have of driving off the spleen and regulating the circulation." - Moby Dick, Herman Melville

Hope this helps!

Comment: Good one!  Although not exactly the word i was looking for...